# PM web-app for non-programmers with google apps

Tags: pm-software

I am thinking of improving project management in our small international advocacy group (< 10 people spread in several countries). We currently do everything by e-mail. We are already using free Google Apps and there are quite many project management apps, I am at loss which one to choose. Our requirements are:

- free
- it's for non-programmers - as simple as possible, minimal number of fields - just task description, assignee(s), task status
- google apps integration, including simple way to convert email->task
- 2-level structure 1. projects 2. tasks
- (optional) people from outside our domain can access it

We have our webhosting where I can install apps if necessary, but I'd prefer ready to use hosted solution. It would help me much if you can share recommendations.

Comment: It's a question about software recommendations (off-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Pivotal Tracker may meet your requirements. Note, that they have recently changed their pricing structure but I think you may qualify for their free plan.

- Very simple web interface
- Has a good google apps integration: http://pivotallabs.com/users/dan/blog/articles/1861-pivotal-tracker-and-google-apps-together-at-last
- Supports your 2 level project structure
- Open to as many people as you want to invite to a project

At the very least, you can sign up for a free account and give it a try.